# seleccionar una parte específica de un texto

Tags: python, python-3.x

me gustaría saber si hay forma de seleccionar una parte específica de un bloc de notas. por ejemplo, yo tengo un bloc de notas lleno de carácteres aleatorios, y me gustaría poder escoger:
[1 a 5], 
[6 a 10] ,
[10 a 15],
[15 a 20], 
etc...
Aquí un ejemplo de como lo he estado haciendo:

```
d=0
while(True):
   d=d+1
   claves=open("claves.txt")                              
   clave=claves.readline(d)                             
   diccionario[clave]=[proveedores]                          
   claves.close()
```

el problema de esto es que selecciona del inicio hasta el número correspondiente

Comment: ¿ese *1 a 5*, significa 1 fila hasta la 5 fila o 1 caracter hasta el 5 caracter?

Comment: del caracter 1 al caracter 5, luego del caracter 6 hasta el caracter 10, y asi

Comment: Usa `with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:`
    `all_text =myfile.read().replace('\n', '')` `texto_del1_al5 = all_text[0:5]`

Comment: Alex para aclarar la pregunta sería bueno que agregaras o explicaras correctamente la estructura de tu fichero, por ejemplo ¿Todo el contenido está en una línea  o tienes varias líneas? `readline` retorna desde la posición del cursor hasta encontrar un carácter de nueva línea  o completar el número de bytes/caracteres pasados al argumento `size`, lo que primero ocurra.  Luego, ¿La idea es extraer en un momento dado una un fragmento en cualquier posición o ir obteniendo a lo largo del programa el contenido del fichero en fragmentos de 5 caracteres empezando desde el principio?

Comment: el punto del fichero en cuestión es pedir datos en específicos ya determinados, y estos meterlos en un diccionario. para esto tengo 2 bloc de notas generados aleatoriamente(no tienen las mismas claves). y mi duda cabe en como poder seleccionar una parte en específica de estos bloc de notas.
imagenes con como estan estructurizado los blocs:
http://prntscr.com/kd2mt2

Comment: osea sería tipo: los datos se almacenan en una lista aleatoria(osea sacas el caracter 1 al 5, luego del 6 al 10 , y todo del bloc de notas 1, y asi según cuantas veces se ingresen los datos), y luego la lista la ingresas en un diccionario cualquier (puede ser con el mismo nombre de "diccionario"), y a esta le asignas una clave aleatoria del otro bloc de notas 2(1 al 5, 6 al 10, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Ya que en tus comentarios indicas que quieres elegir el texto basado en un index (del carácter 1 al 6, etc), es bastante sencillo siempre que sepas la estructura exacta de tu texto. Una manera de hacerlo es la siguiente.

```
ejemplo = "Esto es un texto de ejemplo"
print(ejemplo[:5]) # Solo los primeros cinco caracteres.
print(ejemplo[-5:]) # Solo los últimos cinco caracteres.
print(ejemplo[5:]) # Todo menos los primeros cinco caracteres.
print(ejemplo[:-5]) # Todo menos los últimos cinco caracteres.
print(ejemplo[5:-5]) # Todo menos los primeros y los últimos cinco caracteres.
```

El resultado de esos prints sería:

```
>>> Esto 
>>> emplo
>>> es un texto de ejemplo
>>> Esto es un texto de ej
>>> es un texto de ej
```

Obviamente, puedes cambiar el número 5 por lo que quieras. Te recomiendo que juegues con ello para ir probando cómo funciona. Esta [guía](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) puede ayudarte.

Ahora, si lo que quieres es que sea automático y no tengas que escribir a mano del 1 al 5... del 6 al 10... etc, yo lo que haría sería crear una lista con el texto dividido:

```
ejemplo = "Esto es un texto de ejemplo aun más largo"
trozitos = [ejemplo[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(ejemplo), 5)]
print(trozitos)

>>> ['Esto ', 'es un', ' text', 'o de ', 'ejemp', 'lo au', 'n más', ' larg', 'o']
```

Esto parte en trozos iguales una string, generando una lista de strings de 5 letras cada una (o las que quieras poner). Y ya con eso pues puedes hacer lo que quieras.

Por último, si el texto está eficientemente dividido en lineas, `readlines` es buena idea, pero aun así, podrías optimizar tu código bastante eliminando el loop `while` y simplemente usando una función `for` dentro de un `with` (que abre y cierre el archivo correctamente cuando el loop `for` acaba) para evitar abrir el archivo para cada linea que necesitas, como estás haciendo actualmente. No hace falta que te diga que es horrible tener que abrir el archivo 500 veces si hay 500 lineas. El archivo solo deberías abrirlo una única vez, y leer las 500 lineas de una:

```
with open("claves.txt") as claves:
    for line in claves:
        print(line)
```

Con este código, el bloque `with` abre el archivo una única vez, luego hace un loop para leer cada linea, la imprime, y cuando todas las lineas han sido leidas, se cierra el archivo automáticamente porque eso es lo que hace un `with` en casos así.

**Actualización:** Codigo funcional:

```
trozos = []
with open("claves.txt") as claves:
    for line in claves:
        trozos.append([line[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(line), 5)])
# Ya Haz lo que quieras con la variable trozos. Es una lista del 
# archivo claves.txt dividido en listas más pequeñas de 5 caracteres.
# Te pongo un ejemplo de cómo manipular esa información:
for index, trozo in enumerate(trozos):
    print("Linea {0}: {1}".format(str(index), str(trozo)))
```

Comment: Hola Saelyth, una observación,  `readlines` es extremadamente ineficiente si solo se usa para iterar sobre las líneas del fichero ya que crea una lista con todas y cada una de las líneas del mismo en memoria como paso previo a la iteración, solo se debe usar  si necesitamos efectivamente una lista con todas las líneas del fichero simultáneamente por alguna razón concreta (por ejemplo en algoritmos de ordenación), nunca para ser consumida en un `for`.

Comment: Para leer un fichero línea a línea solo hay que iterar sobre él directamente, `for line in claves`  itera igualmente sobre las líneas  usando internamente la implementación `readline` pero sin crear previamente una lista potencialmente enorme e innecesaria en memoria. Un saludo.

Comment: Buen detalle, había olvidado que funciona de esa manera. Gracias por la corrección.

Comment: por más que lo intento no me funciona
`with open("claves.txt") as claves:`
    `for line in claves:`
        `print(line)`

Comment: Lo has indentado correctamente? Fíjate en que cada una de las tres lineas está en una columna diferente. Tanto `with` como `for` son bloques, y por tanto el código dentro del bloque debe de ir en la siguiente indentación.

Comment: exactamente eso hice, me envía todos los códigos, y como dije arriba lo que yo quería hacer es seleccionar algunas partes del código, ya que el como leer el texto completo y como leer una cantidad de lineas ya se como hacerlo(por si no se entendió lo que pido es que me lea de un punto a otro punto que yo escoja, ej.:del caracter 5 al 20, del 12 al 43, etc)

Comment: Creo que deberías releer la respuesta completa hasta entenderla. Al final te puse un ejemplo con print para que vieras cómo se accede a un archivo únicamente una vez, y se leen todas las lineas. En lugar de leerlo, basta con que lo asocies a tu diccionario, pero eso es obvio. Lo que quiero decir es que si te doy el código pero no lo entiendes, no aprenderás en absoluto. Aun así, actualizare la respuesta.